# Jquery Multiselect dropdown remain open by default

Tags: php, html, css

Is the a way to have the Jquery multiselect dropdown open by default and remain open all the time, could not able to figure it out where to change the settings, help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using this plugin http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/.

Thanks in advance.

Van

Comment: any examples of your existing markup + js? also, you should probably look at a collapsing form if you are trying to re-create a form inside a select box.

Answer (score 3):

This is much easier and allways open!

```
$("#multiselect-demo").multiselect({
    selectedText: "# of # selected"
  , autoOpen: true
  , beforeclose: function (event, ui){ return false; }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

the plugin has a 'auto open' option.

> A boolean value denoting whether or not to automatically open the menu
>   when the widget is initialized.

```
$("#multiselect-demo").multiselect({
    selectedText: "# of # selected",
    autoOpen: true,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $("#multiselect-demo").multiselect("open");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for your reply, I have tried that, it remains open until you trigger a click, then its closes immediately.